# Scraping data using span title and span class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anaconda

I'm using Python Anaconda to scrape data into an Excel sheet. I'm running into some trouble with two sites.

**Site 1**

```
<div id="ember3815" class="ember-view">
<p class="org-top-card-module__company-descriptions Sans-15px-black-55%">
<span class="company-industries org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list">
  Industry
</span>
<span class="org-top-card-module__location org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list">
  City, State
</span>
<span title="62,346 followers" class="org-top-card-module__followers-count org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list">
  62,346 followers
</span>
```

I'm trying to pull the span title. Things I've tried (I've also tried them all as find_all):

```
text = soup.find('span',{'class':"company-industries org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list"})

text = soup.find('p',{'class':"org-top-card-module__company-descriptions Sans-15px-black-55%"})

text = soup.body.find('span', attrs={'class': 'org-top-card-module__location org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list'})

text = soup.find('span',{'class': 'org-top-card-module__location org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list'})
```

I'm sure there are also other things I've tried that I'm not listed, because I don't remember them all. I'm not a programmer, I'm just trying to figure this out to pull data for analysis. Help?

**Site 2**

I need to pull the value 8,052 from the html below.

```
<section class="zwlfE">
<div class="nZSzR">...</div>
<ul class="k9GMp ">
<li class="Y8-fY ">...</li>
<li class-"Y8-fY ">
<a class="g47SY " title="8,052">8,052</span>" followers"
</a>
</li>
<li class="Y8-fY ">...</li>
</ul>
<div class="-vDIg">...</div>
</section>
```

I have tried:

- text = soup.find('span',{'class': "g47SY "})
- similar to above but with the div and li tags

Everything I've tried results in [].

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

To get the `span title`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ="""<div id="ember3815" class="ember-view">
<p class="org-top-card-module__company-descriptions Sans-15px-black-55%">
<span class="company-industries org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list">
  Industry
</span>
<span class="org-top-card-module__location org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list">
  City, State
</span>
<span title="62,346 followers" class="org-top-card-module__followers-count org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list">
  62,346 followers
</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print( soup.find("span", class_="org-top-card-module__followers-count org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list")["title"])
```

**Output:**

```
62,346 followers
```

*And for site2*

```
print( soup.find("a", class_="g47SY")["title"])
```

Comment: import requests
call = requests.get('site')
page = call.text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
print( soup.find("span", class_="org-top-card-module__followers-count org-top-card-module__dot-separated-list")["title"])

Comment: What I get as a result is "TypeError: 'Nonetype' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: I get the same error both when I try the print(soup...) you suggest above.

Comment: check if your content is in `call.text` Sometime data can be loaded via JS

Comment: I printed call.text and I am seeing content there (but there's so much that it's hard to tell if that particular content is there). What's JS? Javascript?